# Hide one image and display another on hover

Tags: css, hover

I have 2 images placed one on top of another, and what I'm trying to do is to change the opacity based on hover on parent.

Meaning that by default hovethumb's opacity is set to 0. But when I hover on index then hoverthumb's opacity should be changed to 1 and bdata's opacity should be changed to 0.5

But the styling doesn't work... The stylings I use are `div.productindex:hover > div.hoverthumb`  & `div.productindex:hover > div.bdata`

Can someone help me figure out to target them correctly?

My php code :

```
<div class="index ">

    <div class="bdata">                     

                    <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('')?></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="hoverthumb clearfix"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/buy.png" width="50px" ;></div>         

</div>
```

also how to align the image exactly in the centre of the box index

```
.index{
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom:10px;    
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }
.hoverthumb{
position:absolute;
opacity:0;
clear:both;
}
div.index:hover > div.bdata{
opacity:0.5;
 border: thin outset #EC008C;  
}

div.index:hover > div.hoverthumb{
opacity:1;
}

.thumb{
width:100%;
}

.thumb img{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: `div.index:hover:after` is it a mistake? there are no children allowed inside `:after/:before` pseudoelements

Comment: yes...was troubleshooting the code...tht part got left behind

Comment: you have also a `clearfix;` defined: please validate your css so you can be sure to avoid parsing error

Comment: changed to clear:both